# relative path of an xpath expression inside a YANG list

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, ietf-netmod-yang, ietf-restconf

I have the following YANG model:

```
list machines {
                key "name";
                leaf "name" {
                    type string;
                }
                leaf link {
                    type leafref {
                            path "../name";
                    }
                }
}
```

Suppose there are three elements in the list:

```
"machines" : [
    { "name": "a" },
    { "name": "b" },
    { "name": "c" }
]
```

If I want to set `"link"` for element `b`, the valid values for `"link"` are `"a", "b", "c"` or just `"b"`?

I didn't find answer in [RFC7950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950). And in [pyangbind](https://github.com/robshakir/pyangbind/tree/master/docs), only `"b"` can be set. But I'm not sure that is the right behavior.

If `../name` here can only reference `"b"`, what is the correct path to reference `"a", "b", "c"`, that is, all names of list elements?

If `../name` here can reference `"a", "b", "c"`, what is the correct path to reference only `"b"`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what RFC7950 says for lists:

> The "list" statement is used to define an interior data node in the
> schema tree. A list node may exist in multiple instances in the data
> tree.  Each such instance is known as a list entry.

Despite your JSON encoded instance document seemingly suggesting that only one instance of the `machines` list exists within it, there are actually three list instances. The name you chose for the list deepens this confusion, as the recommended name for a list definition would be "machine". An enveloping container would take the plural form of the name.

In XML encoding, the above becomes more obvious.

```xml
<machines>
  <name>a</name>
</machines>
<machines>
  <name>b</name>
</machines>
<machines>
  <name>c</name>
</machines>
```

> > If I want to set "link" for element b, the valid values for "link" are "a", "b", "c" or just "b"?

A leafref path expression is a subset of XPath. The same rules apply, you are just limited in what you can select with the expression - it is intended to select one or more leaf instances. XPath always works on a tree of objects and this tree is (somewhat awkwardly) defined in RFC7950 - the document refers to this tree as the `accessible tree` and it consists of instantiated data nodes (subset of a data tree). This is described in [Section 6.4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-6.4.1).

In addition to the accessible tree, a context node is also important (relative expressions refer to it implicitly). Here is what RFC7950 says about the context node in your example.

> the context node is the node in the data tree for which the "path" statement is defined

This would be the `link` instance in your case, a sibling to the `name` instance with value `b`. Here's a quick pseudo- data tree:

```
machines[1]
 +-name(a)
machines[2]
 +-name(b)
 +-link
machines[3]
 +-name(c)
```

The expression first proceeds to select the parent of `link`. There is always only one parent for any given data node instance and in your case that would be the list instance that has both siblings mentioned before as children (`machines[2]`). The expression then proceeds to select children that have a `name` name, which is the instance of `name` with value `b`.

This means the only valid value for your `link` node is `b`. This only applies to your specific example.

> > If ../name here can only reference "b", what is the correct path to reference "a", "b", "c", that is, all names of list elements?

Use an absolute expression or go one parent further, then back again:

- `//machines/name` (replace the `//` with an absolute path to
  `machines`)
- `../../machines/name`

Both of these will then first select all instantiated `machines`.

Note: this is just how XPath works. The other alternative would apply if RFC7950 text would say "there is only one list instance with multiple entries" or something along those lines.

Comment: your explanation about the definition of the list statement is very clear, and that is the key for me to understand. Could you explain more about `There is always only one parent for any given node and in your case that would be the list instance that has both siblings mentioned before as children.` I don't get the meaing of `that has both siblings mentioned before as children`.

Comment: and could you take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946437/json-encoding-of-payload-to-restconf-server-for-multiple-resources-creation, I have a follow-up question in my last comment. Thanks.

Comment: @password636, I edited the part which you were asking about.